# How to implement a Modular ES2015 JavaScript App structure

Tags: ecmascript-6, object-literal

I'm trying to implement a simple and easy to manage as the app extends structure. I am using ES2015 modules to keep things neat, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly to go about it. I have been using Vue.js and I like the idea of an object literal like this:

```
export default {
   data: {},
   methods: {},
   ready(){}
}
```

Their way is very clean and readable. I know that under the hood they do allot of things, but I wanted to have something really simple and clean like so:

```js
const navbar = {
  data: {
    classes: {},
  },
  init() {
    this.data.classes = {
      hamburgerActive: 'hamburger--active',
      showNavbar: 'nav--small--show'
    }
    this.hooks()
  },
  hooks() {
    $('#nav-trigger').on('click', (e) => {
      const buttonClassList = e.currentTarget.classList,
        nav = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.dataset['target'])
      e.preventDefault()
      if (buttonClassList.contains(this.data.classes.hamburgerActive)) {
        this.methods.close(buttonClassList, nav) // Here I have to do a .call(this) If I want to have the proper this
      } else {
        this.methods.open(buttonClassList, nav) // Here I have to do a .call(this) If I want to have the proper this
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    open(buttonClassList, nav) {
      console.log(this) //Returns {open(), close()} because I call it from its parent .methods
    },
    close(buttonClassList, nav) {
      //some stuff
    }
  }
}

export default navbar
```

and then just import it and run it:

```
import navbar from './navbar'
navbar.init()
```

Does anyone have any tips for me to make this better. I have been reading about ES6 Classes being bad and all, but I think if I used them here I would have been done already. 
I tried searching around stack overflow but most of the questions are from 2011...

Comment: How your question is Vue related?

Comment: As i said I would have loved to have a Vue like structure of the components, its clean and readable. Of course the question is not in any way vue directly related.

Comment: This is a more likely personal stuff. It's clean enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because `methods` contains all the methods, all of their `this` will point to their immediate parent object (methods object). So solutions are:

1. use `method.open.call(this, params) //pass what ever context-this you want` which is kind of ugly
2. `this.whatEver` use `navbar.whatEver`, that way we remove the problem with this. Ofc we cannot reuse a function elsewhere, like reassigning `this` but I think its a small price to pay.
3. Just move all methods to the top level of the exported object(not nest them inside methods) then `this` will be what we want.

If anyone has a better solution I am really open to ideas.